# Laravel tests aggressively caches json-requests

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, phpunit, laravel-8

I want to test how an API endpoint behaves for different users. I create three users with their corresponding JWT tokens and access the endpoint accordingly. The first one works flawlessly but the two following requests just act as if they were done by the first user.

The tokens are definitely the ones for the corresponding users. Manually accessing this route works. Am I missing something?

Did anyone else experience this problem? Any solutions?

```php
    /**
     * We want to test, if a private profile and/or status is visible to the user itself, a following user, a
     * not-following user and a guest. Therefore we create three users: bob (private profile), gertrud (following bob),
     * and alice (not following bob). Also Gertrud and bob will have their own seperate check-ins.
     */
    public function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->users = $this->createAliceBobAndGertrud();
    }

   /**
     * Watching a private profile is characterized by being able to see ones statuses on a profile page.
     * If the statuses are returned as null, you're not allowed to see the statuses.
     *
     * @test
     */
    public function view_profile_of_private_user() {
        // Can Alice see the profile of Bob? => no
        $alice = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->users->alice->token])
                      ->get(route('api.v0.user', ['username' => $this->users->bob->user->username]));
        $alice = json_decode($alice->getContent(), true);

        $this->assertEquals(null, $alice['statuses']);

        // Can Bob see the profile of bob? => yes
        $bob = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->users->bob->token])
                    ->get(route('api.v0.user', ['username' => $this->users->bob->user->username]));
        $bob = json_decode($bob->getContent(), true);
        $this->assertNotEquals(null, $bob['statuses']);

        // Can Gertrud see the profile of bob? => yes
        $gertrud = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->users->gertrud->token])
                        ->get(route('api.v0.user', ['username' => $this->users->bob->user->username]));
        $gertrud = json_decode($gertrud->getContent(), true);
        $this->assertNotEquals(null, $gertrud['statuses']);
    }

    /**
     * This method creates thee users: Gertrud, Alice and Bob.
     * Bob is a private profile, followed by Gertrud. Alice is a seperate user, following nobody.
     * Bob has one check in.
     *
     * @return stdClass
     * @throws \App\Exceptions\AlreadyFollowingException
     */
    public function createAliceBobAndGertrud(): stdClass {
        $data          = new stdClass();
        $data->bob     = new stdClass();
        $data->gertrud = new stdClass();
        $data->alice   = new stdClass();
        // Create Gertrud, Alice and Bob
        $data->bob->user                     = $this->createGDPRAckedUser();
        $data->bob->token                    = $data->bob->user->createToken('token')->accessToken;
        $data->bob->user->privacy_ack_at     = now();
        $data->gertrud->user                 = $this->createGDPRAckedUser();
        $data->gertrud->token                = $data->gertrud->user->createToken('token')->accessToken;
        $data->gertrud->user->privacy_ack_at = now();
        $data->alice->user                   = $this->createGDPRAckedUser();
        $data->alice->token                  = $data->alice->user->createToken('token')->accessToken;
        $data->alice->user->privacy_ack_at   = now();
        $data->bob->user->save();
        $data->gertrud->user->save();
        $data->alice->user->save();

        // Create new CheckIn for Bob
        $now = new DateTime("+2 day 12:45");
        $this->checkin("Frankfurt Hbf", $now, $data->bob->user);

        // Make Gertrud follow bob and make bob's profile private
        UserController::destroyFollow($data->alice->user, $data->bob->user);
        UserController::createFollow($data->gertrud->user, $data->bob->user);
        $data->bob->user->update(['private_profile' => 'true']);

        $this->assertTrue($data->bob->user->private_profile);

        return $data;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are calling `withHeaders` each time without clearing the previous `Authorization` header and only the first one (Alice) gets checked. I would debug/dump the request object after each call to verify the headers.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me into the right direction!
The headers were the correct ones for every request, but my authorized user was always the same. By using `$this->actingAs($this->users->alice->user)` before a request, the authorized user finally is the right one.